# How to change the menu color

Tags: php, menus, css

I need to change the menu color of the wordpress 2011 theme to transparent.

this is the header

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
            <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
            <?php /* Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
            <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
            <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
            <?php /* Our navigation menu. If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assigned to the primary location is the one used. If one isn't assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #access -->
</header><!-- #branding -->
```

As you can see, the menu uses php. I have no clue how to style php.

Thanks

Comment: The menu is *generated* using PHP. The output is HTML, which you should know how to style. Have a look at your website source to see the generated classes, elements, and IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the answer you're looking for?

Go to your **.css** file and replace this

```
#access {
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(37, 37, 37), rgb(10, 10, 10)) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px auto 6px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

With this

```
#access {
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px auto 6px;
    width: 100%;
}
```